# mvvmcross binding UILabel

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to bind ULabel to a Command in a core but can't figure out why it is not working for me. I read that UILabel is bindable to a default Text property so I have the following simple tester to demonstrate:

in Touch code I have the following ViewDidLoad:

```
        var tipLabel = new UILabel(new RectangleF(10, 20, 300, 40));
        Add(tipLabel);

        var loginBtn = new UIButton(UIButtonType.RoundedRect) { Frame = new RectangleF(10, 100, 100, 40) };
        loginBtn.SetTitle("Set Text", UIControlState.Normal);

        var tap = new UITapGestureRecognizer(() =>
        {
            tipLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        });
        loginBtn.AddGestureRecognizer(tap);
        Add(loginBtn);


        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstView, FirstViewModel>();
        set.Bind(tipLabel).For(p=>p.Text).To(vm=>vm.TestCommand);
        set.Apply();
```

and in a core:

```
     private MvxCommand _testCommand;

    public ICommand TestCommand
    {
        get { return this._testCommand ?? (this._testCommand = new MvxCommand(this.Test)); }
    }


    public void Test()
    {
    }
```

what am I missing?

Thank you
Mark

Comment: Command should be used for actions like Click and etc. Why you binding text field to Command? You should bind it to string property

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively binding the Text property to a command.  This won't work.  I would use a UIButton and adjust its properties so it looks like a label then bind to its click event to change the button label.

Comment: yes thank you, button would work, i just thought that any control can be binded to a command. Say it is not UILabel but Grid where I want to add binding to row selection to a command. Does this require some sort of custom binding, do you know?

Comment: In order to bind the command it needs to be something you can actually bind a command to... Like the Click event or some other similar event.  You can look at the iOS documentation and see what properties the control has and what might work.  So in your case you can't bind a command to something that is expecting a string.  In your example of the row you would bind to the onClick event of the grid or table

Comment: There is a `Tap` behavior - that can be used to bind commands - e.g. `set.Bind(tipLabel).For("Tap").To(vm=>vm.TestCommand);`

Comment: thank you, i guess i should of start my question differently. I am using infragistics grid and at some point I get an event that the row was selected. I want to trigger command to core object moving on to the next screen. Since I do not know what to bind a command to i was thinking binding it to some text field in UILabel that I update on row selection which would trigger the command. What is the way to trigger a command w/o binding to any elements like in my case. Thank you again